# Logistic regression interpretation (multiple dependent variables)

Tags: regression, logistic, inference, survey

I'm running logistic regressions in R, for a survey I did. 
I have a binary categorical variable (i.e. expectation of participants regarding a risk-return tradeoff) as the dependent variable. I want to see if I can explain the results with three independent variables: gender (factor), age (int), education (factor). The results I get are not significant. I am unsure if I missed something or if the results just aren't significant. Do I have to be careful with anything in particular, when running a regression like this? sample size is 100.

My code: 
`Logit.Mrisk.Rpr<- glm( Data_Rpr$Mrisk~ Data_Rpr$gender + Data_Rpr$age + Data_Rpr$edu, family = "binomial")`

`summary(Logit.Mrisk.Rpr)`

My output:

````
glm(formula = Data_Rpr$Grisk ~ Data_Rpr$gender + Data_Rpr$age + 
    Data_Rpr$edu, family = "binomial")

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.2766  -0.9190  -0.7345   1.2047   1.9483  

Coefficients:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)                           -1.61888    0.80960  -2.000   0.0455 *
Data_Rpr$genderWeiblich                0.13407    0.46997   0.285   0.7754  
Data_Rpr$age                           0.02450    0.01259   1.946   0.0517 .
Data_Rpr$eduBachelor Abschluss        -0.68011    0.90515  -0.751   0.4524  
Data_Rpr$eduDoktorat                  -1.04707    1.16957  -0.895   0.3706  
Data_Rpr$eduHöhere Berufsausbildung   -0.54895    0.63357  -0.866   0.3862  
Data_Rpr$eduMaster Abschluss          -0.59907    0.91652  -0.654   0.5133  
Data_Rpr$eduMaturität oder Äquivalent -0.37085    0.60296  -0.615   0.5385  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 128.21  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 121.81  on 92  degrees of freedom
AIC: 137.81

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4```
````

Comment: Looking at your coefficients, seems like the error is really huge. One problem you might have is age. Did you center the age?

Comment: Hi! thx for your answer!!! No, I did not... should I, however, take out the non-significant predictors like education and age? if I do so my predictor gender gets a higher p-value, which I could report... any articles or recommendations, which explain a more structured way of targeting the problem ?

Comment: Try scaling the age first.. If you need to control for age and education, and I can see the effect of education is quite huge, then you should not do that

Comment: yes, I am supposed to control for age and education, do you conclude that the effect is huge by calculating the expected probability from the log-odds ( e.g. Data$rpr$eduMaster abschluss (1/1+exp(-0.599))=0.64) ? To control for variables do i even need to look at p-values? sorry for my rookie Q's haha new to this...

Comment: no.. the coefficients are log odds ratio, so for example, eduDoktorat has -1.04707 means by being in eduDoktorat, the odds of being 1 is  exp(-1.04707) times. no worries, sometimes i need to check too, after doing too many regressions. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-do-i-interpret-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression/

Comment: what is the hypothesis you are testing?

Comment: thanks for the clarification! I actually just want to check if age gender and education have an effect on the expectation a participant might have, therefore the p-value would be necessary right?...  the idea of the study focusses on differences in expectations between samples, but I haven't figured out the statistics behind comparing the samples... Thank you for the link!!

Comment: you can check using anova(Logit.Mrisk.Rpr,test="Chisq"). this test all the terms and you can see what it's like. there's also the possibility that you don't have enough samples to reject the hypothesis that the effect is zero. again.. scale the age first